# on click load images on the same page

Tags: theme-development

[This](http://www.abiglittlebiz.com/trevelle/home-designs/) is my website. On the left there is a list.

I want to do is that whenever I click on Amazon 1 then page should display that specific images. When I click on amazon 2 it should display data for amazon 2 on the same page.

How can I do it in WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your site isn't setup to do any of this - and this **isn't the solution** to your problems but it'll do what you asked (click items and change images on the same page). You'll need to construct your page better with a combination of [php](https://generatewp.com), [custom page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/), [custom post types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types), [custom galleries](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_WordPress_Gallery), [custom fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/), [queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)... a lot of different things that will require a much longer answer and far more education on WordPress.

The menu on the right currently is just a paragraph with text.

This script (using jQuery and the Chrome console) will clear it out, make new menu items and when each are click they will replace the main featured image with a placeholder using data on the menu item.

This should help you moving forward to see how jQuery can help but you are missing a ton of classes to target specific things. Case in point, the selector for the main image is `.col-md-9 img` which is far too generic. Maybe change it to something like `class="col-md-9 featured-image"`.

```
// your menu
var $ul = jQuery('ul.homedesign');

// clear it out cause it's useless as is
$ul.html('');

// now make some fake links
var count = 6; for ( var i = 1; i <= 6; i++ ) {

   // Create a new list item with click handler
   $item = jQuery ( '<li data-item="' + i + '" ><a>Amazon ' + i + '</a></li>' );

   $item.on('click', function(evt){
        // ignore default, shoudl be li anyway...
        if(evt) evt.preventDefault();

        // scope   
        var $this = jQuery(this);

        // get the id for ... whatever
        var inx = $this.data( 'item' );

        // should be labeled better
        // but, replace the main image with a label using the stored id
        jQuery('.col-md-9 img').attr('src', '//placehold.it/634x341/eee/222/&text=' + inx );
   });

   // add our new item to the list
   $ul.append ( $item );
}
```

Comment: Looks good. But can you please elaborate it? where do I place this?

Comment: ncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /(…)

Comment: What did you do to get that error. There isn't any regular expressions in this code. Did it give you a line number & source?

Comment: Superb. Now its working. Sir I really appreciate your kindness. one thing more. when I entered this code. it shows numbers 1,2,3,4,5 on each link. What I want to do this I want to replace that big image, the text on its left and three bottom Images. How do I do this?

Comment: can i do this with custom post types?

Comment: yes, you'll need a custom post type and a page that renders the contents of those pages. Check out http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/211365/84219 for an example of a custom post type and loop on a page with a custom template attached. Also take a look at https://generatewp.com/ to generate some of your code so you know you didn't make any typos.